# jquery sortable scroll infinitive

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have problem with jquery sortable with scroll.
Example available on - http://jsfiddle.net/n5eL2e55/1/

My code:
HTML:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item">item 1</li>
    <li class="item">item 2</li>
    <li class="item">item 3</li>
    <li class="item">item 4</li>
    <li class="item">item 5</li>  
    <li class="item">item 6</li>
    <li class="item">item 7</li>    
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $(".list").sortable({
        items: ".item",
        axis : "y",
        helper:'clone',
        containment: "parent",
        scroll: true
    }).disableSelection();
    $(".list").disableSelection();
});
```

CSS:

```
.list{
    overflow: scroll;
    border:1px solid red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}
.item{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Problem is when you dragging item from top to bottom last item and you keep scrolling to bottom. Problem is that jquery sortable allows to scroll to bottom without any limit(scrolling area keeps increase)
Image available on - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljd04.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can interfere with `scrollTop` of `scrollParent` on `sort` event to prevent it from going higher than `scrollParent` `height`. The result is not perfect, but there's probably a way to improve it.

Like this:

```
sort: function (e, ui) {
            var scrollParent = $(e.target).sortable('instance').scrollParent;
            if( scrollParent.scrollTop()>scrollParent.height()){
               scrollParent.scrollTop(scrollParent.height())
            }

        }
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zt2sd3kv/1/

---

**Updated version of solution provided by Julien Grégoire**

I added callculation for maximal scrollTop on start and restoring if scrollTop increases this stored value - http://jsfiddle.net/n5eL2e55/2/

```
$(".list").sortable({
    items: ".item",
    axis : "y",
    helper:'clone',
    containment: "parent",
    scroll: true,
    start: function(e, ui) {
        //set max scrollTop for sortable scrolling
        var scrollParent = $(this).data("ui-sortable").scrollParent;
        var maxScrollTop = scrollParent[0].scrollHeight - scrollParent.height() - ui.helper.height();
        $(this).data('maxScrollTop', maxScrollTop);
    },
    sort: function (e, ui) {
        //check if scrolling is out of boundaries
        var scrollParent = $(this).data("ui-sortable").scrollParent,
            maxScrollTop = $(this).data('maxScrollTop');
        if(scrollParent.scrollTop() > maxScrollTop){
            scrollParent.scrollTop(maxScrollTop);
        }
    },
}).disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use this fiddle as a reference. Its working as per your requirements.

http://jsfiddle.net/omegak/2bHSG/

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
    axis: "y",
    containment: "parent",
    cursor: "move",
    items: "li",
    tolerance: "pointer",
});
ul {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 190px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
li {
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I saw it. Problem appears when you add "position: relative" or "position:absolute" to "ul". But I need position "relative" in my case. So I want to find another solution

Answer (score 0):

Improvement to the solution from **Julien Grégoire** and **spacemanCoder**.

I needed a way to prevent horizontal scrolling in a flexbox container without the `y` axis constraint.

Basically I've only added following code to the `sort` event handler

```
if (scrollParentEl.scrollLeft()) {
    scrollParentEl.scrollLeft(0);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n5eL2e55/5/

Answer (score 0):

Later versions of Sortable added the option `scrollFn`.
You can use it to limit the auto-scrolling any way you want. 
Here is an example of how to allow auto-scrolling on y axis only:

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
        ...
        scrollFn: function (offsetX, offsetY, originalEvent, touchEvt, hoverTargetEl)
        {
            if (offsetY) $('#scroll_parent')[0].scrollTop += offsetY; // scroll only vertically
        },
```

https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable#scrollfn-option